# LINQ query to return whether an item is found in an array?

Tags: c#, linq

I am learning LINQ, and I am not sure how to write a query to return a boolean indicating whether an item is found in an array. I have a very simple list:

```
var targetProperties = new string[] { "SelectedDate", "SelectedMonth" };
```

I need to write a LINQ query that will return true if an item passed in is in the array, and false if it isn't. What would that query look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
bool answer = targetProperties.Any(x => x == "SelectedDate");
```

Answer (score 8):

`targetProperties.Contains("SelectedDate")` ?

Comment: Arrays don't have a `Contains` method. You need to use the static Array.IndexOf method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof.aspx

Comment: It is a linq extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, which is implemented on C# arrays.

Comment: 8 upvotes... 2 more and I'm a populist... http://stackoverflow.com/badges/62/populist